# "little though he wanted to" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "What are we going to do with it?" Hermione asked.
>
> "Keep it safe 'til we work out how to destroy it," Harry replied, and, **little though he wanted to**, he hung the chain around his own neck, dropping the locket out of sight beneath his robes, where it rested against his chest beside the pouch Hagrid had given him.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't quite understand "*little though he wanted to*" in this context. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Little" here is an adverb modifying "wanted." Literally,

> little though he wanted to

just means

> though he scarcely wanted to

However, it actually means

> he did it even though he did not want to